# de-select a selected radio button on click

Tags: javascript

[image]HTML code: 
.....

```
<input onclick="removeAttr(i)" name="autoselected[]" value="i" class="radio" checked="checked" type="radio">
```

....

```
function removeAttr(i) {

preSelected = $$('[input[type=radio][name=autoselected[]][value=' + i + ']');

 preSelected.each(function (item) {
        // De-Select a selected option in Prototype. 
 });

}
```

any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not magento question. You should only ask magento related question here.

However, I will try to give you heads on.

Try this code:

```
//$ = jQuery;
$(':radio').mousedown(function(e){
  var $self = $(this);
  if( $self.is(':checked') ){
    var uncheck = function(){
      setTimeout(function(){$self.removeAttr('checked');},0);
    };
    var unbind = function(){
      $self.unbind('mouseup',up);
    };
    var up = function(){
      uncheck();
      unbind();
    };
    $self.bind('mouseup',up);
    $self.one('mouseout', unbind);
  }
});
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957207/how-to-check-uncheck-radio-button-on-click)